# Fatal exception: main on textView

Tags: android, eclipse, textview

I've hit a problem crashing my app and writing this on logcat:

> 10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x0
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:239)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3844)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.example.lightalarmclock.AddBox.onClick(AddBox.java:89)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
>   10-18 13:13:13.950: E/AndroidRuntime(748):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

My app is updating text on keypress, a bit like an android alarm clock app (4.3) when adding an alarm where you press buttons and it sends them from left to right.

So I came up with following:

```
if (pos1 == 0) {
            TextView Pos1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView05);
            Pos1.setText("1");
            pos1 = 1;
        } else {

            //Moving all positions for a one
            TextView Pos1 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
            Pos1.setText(pos3);
            pos4 = pos3;
            TextView Pos2 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
            Pos2.setText(pos2);
            pos3 = pos2;
            TextView Pos3 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView01);
            Pos3.setText(pos1);
            pos2 = pos1;

            //imputing 
            TextView Pos5 = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.TextView05);
            Pos5.setText("1");

            pos1 = 0;
        }
```

And the part that causes the problem is in "else" statement //moving all positions comment is the part where the game crashes.
So in app GUI you press number 1, it draws instead of 0 in far right (this part works), then you press 1 again and its spouse to move  the previous 1 to the left and add another 1 in far right, but this crashes my app.

I've tried to fix it and google it but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to provide a String to setText, otherwise android will lookup in the Resource for a string with id the integer you provide. So you have to change

```
Pos1.setText(pos3);
```

with

```
 Pos1.setText(String.valueOf(pos3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't assign integer value directly to setText method, because value should be a string. If value is integer then android will start looking for resource string with id(integer you provided).

> Pos1.setText(""+pos3);

or

> Pos1.setText(Integer.toString(pos3));

Answer (score -1):

your pos3 , pos2 are being referenced as int id from `R.string` . you have to convert them to text and then set text